# Primefaces -MouseOver -Method call - occuring multiple time

Tags: primefaces

i need to make a backbean call on mouse over of a image and update the tooltip of the image .Kindly help me by saying how can i do this ?

Comment: onmouseover event for javascript, so you can make a backbean call, you fire button click, and button will call backbean method and you can update tooltip of the image via oncomplete method of button.(you can hide button for your UI)

Comment: Can you please Explain in detail with some code :( ...

Answer (score 1):

onmouseover was execute in client, so my approach is: create a hidden button, when mouseover event fire, it will fire click event to that button, that button will call **backbean**(meant by you), after that, button's oncomplete will update image's title with info get from bean(or from anything):

**Facelets:**

```
<h:form id="form">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test(){
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('form:btn')).click();                
            }
            function test2(xhr,status,args){
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('form:gi')).attr("title",args.sotest);  
            }
        </script>
        <p:commandButton process="@this" actionListener="#{userBean.test}" oncomplete="test2(xhr,status,args);" style="display:none !important" id="btn" value="SB"/>
        <h:graphicImage id="gi" onmouseover="test();" url="/resources/images/banner2.png" title="123"/>
    </h:form>
```

**BackBean**(meant by you):

```
public void test() {
        RequestContext reqCtx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        reqCtx.addCallbackParam("sotest", "image's title here");
    }
```